# DateTimeOffset formatting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to get formatted string from DateTimeOffset type which should look like this: 20. July 2009. (with dots), i tried with this code:

```
Birthday.ToString("dd. MMMM yyyy.")
```

but I only get empty string.

**EDIT:**
I use this in ASP.NET MVC3 C# project with Razor.
Here's the complete line:

```
@Html.Label(Model.Birthday.ToString("dd. MMMM yyyy."))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you've given should be fine - I suspect you haven't actually assigned the return value to anything. For example:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        DateTimeOffset dto = new DateTimeOffset(2009, 7, 20,
                                                0, 0, 0, TimeSpan.Zero);
        string text = dto.ToString("dd. MMMM yyyy.");
        Console.WriteLine(text); // Prints 20. July 2009. on my machine
    }
}
```

(Obviously you may want to specify the culture to use, too.)

Comment: Sorry but `I suspect you haven't actually assigned the return value to anything`, can you elaborate please what you mean here by `return value`

Comment: @HarshBaid: I meant that just calling the method doesn't do anything. Now that you've shown the MVC side of things, we should be able to sort it out. It's not clear to me why that isn't working, but I'm not an MVC person. If you just change it to `@Html.Label("20. July 2009.")` what happens? I suspect you'll get the same result.

Comment: okkiez. I am bit of low in reputation in English so asked.. :D

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
Birthday.ToString("dd'.' MMMM yyyy'.'")
```

I tried this code on my pc (VS2010) and it works as expected:

```
DateTime Birthday = new DateTime(2009, 7, 20);
string s = Birthday.ToString("dd'.' MMMM yyyy'.'");
DateTimeOffset Birthday1 = new DateTimeOffset(Birthday);
string s1 = Birthday1.ToString("dd'.' MMMM yyyy'.'");
```

Both **s** and **s1** are reported correctly.

Comment: There's no need to quote the periods here. See my answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet: yes, you're right... I've just used it to be sure that some custom date separator on user pc could not lead to some error. Anyway, you're alway right ;)

Comment: @JonSkeet: even because user told us he tried that syntax and didn't work... so I tried something different...